# spanning a timer in background for metro apps

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

I would like to start an background timer in METRO app when my app goes to suspended state. Is there any way I could do this. According to msdn site " If an app does not return from the suspending event within 5 seconds, Windows assumes that the app has stopped responding and terminates it." 
In the above case I will not be able to do any tasks with my timer. Please let me know how can I spawn the timer in background when my application goes to suspended state. I am using WinJS for coding.

Answer (score 2):

You likely need to use the background task API:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/05/24/being-productive-in-the-background-background-tasks.aspx

You can both kick off a timer for the background task, and declare in your manifest an interval for the work.

If you don't want the work to happen while you are suspended a set interval timer will work, and will fire at the correct interval when you do come out of the suspended state.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've read about something like this before. Exactly what you want is not possible, because after an app is suspended its code stops running, so it cannot run its own timer in the background while suspended. However you should be able to get the same sort of effect if on the suspend event, you save the system time that the app is closing down to e.g. isolated storage/settings, then on the reactivation event you can get this value if it exists, and from there calculate how long the app has been in suspension by comparing the current time against the stored time

Comment: Is it possible to start an background task when the app goes to suspended state ?

Comment: It would be possible to do anything in the on suspension event, but if it takes longer than the seconds that the windows runtime allows for an app to suspend, then your app will be terminated instead and have to be completely restarted